# Python debugging in jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, breakpoints, pdb, ipdb

I am trying to understand debugging in jupyter notebooks. As per my understanding applying `breakpoint()` is the way to go about it but I am landing into a few issues that I describe below. I have a file named `test_debugger.py` in `./` that I am using as a prop in my little understanding endeavor.

```
#./test_debugger.py

def fun1(a):
    print(a)
    breakpoint()
    if a > 3:
        print(a+1)
        breakpoint()
    print(a+2)
    breakpoint()
    return None
```

Setup:

```
from test_debugger import *
```

**Issues**:

- **breakpoint() enters into debugging the interactive shell**:

```
print(5)
breakpoint()
fun1(4)
breakpoint()
```

Running the above code gives me

```
5
--Return--
None
> <ipython-input-2-4276bdd18b42>(2)<module>()
      1 print(5)
----> 2 breakpoint()
      3 fun1(4)
      4 breakpoint()

ipdb>
```

I press `n` and I want to jump to the next line in the cell but it gets into debugging the interactive shell I guess. Upon pressing `n`I get:

```
ipdb> n
    [... skipped 1 hidden frame]

    [... skipped 1 hidden frame]

    [... skipped 1 hidden frame]

    [... skipped 1 hidden frame]

> /home/nitin/miniconda/envs/nyraml386/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py(3330)run_ast_nodes()
   3328                     to_run.append((node, 'single'))
   3329 
-> 3330                 for node,mode in to_run:
   3331                     if mode == 'exec':
   3332                         mod = Module([node], [])

ipdb>
```

**Question**: How do I get the desired functionality of `n` (jump to next line in code written by me while remaining in the same function score) and `s` (jump to the next line in code written by me while switching the function scope wherever necessary).

- **PYTHONBREAKPOINT not available in jupyter notebook**

The behavior expected: I have read that in case I want to disable all `breakpoint()` then I can set the env variable `PYTHONBREAKPOINT` to manage the behavior of `breakpoint()`. Specifically, I can set `PYTHONBREAKPOINT=0` to disable `breakpoint()`

The behavior seen: `PYTHONBREAKPOINT` is not a variable available at all in jupyter notebook. Even if I set it equal to 0 that does not alter the disable `breakpoint()`. It is as if nothing happened

**Question**: How to manage `breakpoint()` when operating in jupyter notebooks. What is the way to bring in `PYTHONBREAKPOINT` into the notebook